# Run extendscript automatic

Tags: automator, extendscript

I have a jsx file for After effects that runs automatic via OSX Automator. But when it suppose to render the movie i get errors.

This is my script fot Automator:
on run {input, parameters}

```
tell application "Adobe After Effects CC 2015"
    DoScriptFile ":Users:youandi:Desktop:WeatherApp:script:weather.jsx"
end tell


return input
```

end run

The this is the error After effects give me.

Unable to execute script at line 399. After effects error: could not create folder Adobe After Effects Auto-Save

This is the script where it goes wrong i think:

function addToRender(){

```
for(var i=1; i<= items; i++){
    curItem = proj.item(i);
    if(curItem instanceof CompItem){
        if (curItem.name == "WeatherStation"){      
            app.project.renderQueue.items.add(curItem);
            var oldName;
            var newPath = "~/Desktop/WeatherApp/MoviesRender/";
            oldName = "WeatherStation.mov";
            app.project.renderQueue.item(1).outputModule(1).file = new File(newPath+oldName);
            app.project.renderQueue.render();

        }
    }
}
```

}

// i have tried app.project.renderQueue.render(curItem)

Answer (score 0):

Does your folder exist? Extendscript can't create folders when creating files. You need to create the folder as well. See the example below.

```
if(Folder('~/Desktop/testing').exists !== true){
    Folder('~/Desktop/testing').create();
    }
var f = new File ('~/Desktop/testing/file.txt');
f.open('w');
f.write('test');
f.close();
```

Comment: Yes it does exist cause when i run the script in Extendscript it works perfect but when the script runs automatic via Automator i get an error

Comment: Maybe he doesn't like the paths with `~`

Comment: Can you try to extract the part that just does the "add item to render queue and render" thingy. If you do that I can try it on my machine.